# Some books write $V(\vec{r})$ instead of $V(r)$ as a notation for the electric potential, so which one is right?

Tags: classical-mechanics, symmetry, potential, potential-energy, voltage

Some books write $V(\vec{r})$ instead of $V(r)$ as a notation for the electric potential, so can the electric potential depends also on the direction?

Comment: this paragraph makes clear the difference in the notation. For  potential of a a point charge one uses the scalar form of r. When multiple charges are involved the potential a point depends on the vector direction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential#Electric_potential_due_to_a_point_charge

Comment: Consider the potential inside an infinite parallel-plate capacitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, electric potential is a function of the vector position. Sometimes the vector notation is reduced to a scalar due to spherical symmetry.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential#Electric_potential_due_to_a_point_charge